# Run two different web app in same domain with nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain, web-deployment

I'm new in server deployment. For my e-commerce app I've two react projects, one is `storefront` for customers and other is `dashboard` for admins. I've setup my nginx server with the following configuration. I can access my storefront going https://shop.saleortest.com, but I want to access my dashboard using https://shop.saleortest.com/dashboard. This might be done with `reverse proxy`, adding `proxy_pass` inside the `location` block. But I don't know how to achieve this.
I've tried adding this block, here https://admin.shop.saleortest.com running the same server. But it's not working

```js
location /dashboard/ {
   proxy_pass https://admin.shop.saleortest.com;
}
```

As example I can go to this site https://demo.saleor.io/ it's the storefront and if I go to https://demo.saleor.io/dashboard it takes me to `dashboard` app, those are two different react app using the same domain. Here both storefront and dashboard are running in single server? How can I achieve something like this. Thanks.

```js
   
    server {
    server_name shop.saleortest.com;
    root /var/www/html/storefront;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
}

    location /graphql/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/;
  }

location /dashboard/ {
   proxy_pass https://admin.gethookedseafood.com;
}


    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/shop.saleortest.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/shop.saleortest.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

    server {
    if ($host = shop.saleortest.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name shop.saleortest.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```